# MapKit - Displaying image in detailCalloutAccessoryView - accessing mapView.selectedAnnotations not working

Tags: swift, mapkit, callout

I have a subclass of `MKPointAnnotation` called `CustomPointAnnotation`:

`class CustomPointAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation {
    var imageName: String!
    var theItemObject: PFObject?
    var theImage: UIImage?
}`

In the view controller dealing with the map (and yes I have the class set to the `MKMapViewDelegate`), I run a function called `getAnnotations()` which successfully adds my various annotations to the map (which happen to be objects retrieved from Parse). Each annotation object has an image associated with it, that's the `theImage` in the class above.

My confusion is how `viewForAnnotation` gets called before `didSelectAnnotationView`. Because of this, I am unable to extract the image stored in the class, which I want to use for the `detailCalloutAccessoryView` of the callout.

Below is my `viewForAnnotation` function:

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

```
    if !(annotation is CustomPointAnnotation) {
        return nil
    }

    print("viewForAnnotation was called!")


    let reuseId = "test"

    var anView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId)

    if anView == nil {

        anView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        anView!.canShowCallout = true

    }

    else {
        anView!.annotation = annotation
    }


    //Set annotation-specific properties **AFTER**
    //the view is dequeued or created...



    let cpa = annotation as! CustomPointAnnotation

    anView!.image = UIImage(named:cpa.imageName)

    let rightButton: UIButton = UIButton(type: .DetailDisclosure)
    rightButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "arrow-icon.png"), forState: .Normal)
    rightButton.tintColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    rightButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("showItemDetail:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    anView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton

    print("about to print the array of selected annotations")
    print(mapView.selectedAnnotations)


    if mapView.selectedAnnotations.count > 0 {

        print("THIS IS NEVER SATISFIED, I WILL NEVER GET HERE, WHY?!")

        //yes, there is an annotation currently selected

        if let selectedAnnotation = mapView.selectedAnnotations[0] as? CustomPointAnnotation {

            fullImageOfItem = selectedAnnotation.theImage

            print("i just set the image")

        }
    }

    else {
        print("there are no selected annotations")
    }




    let myCustomImage: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: fullImageOfItem)

    anView!.detailCalloutAccessoryView = myCustomImage

    return anView

}
```

I don't understand why `mapView.selectedAnnotations.count` is always 0. Because of this, I am unable to set my `fullImageOfItem` variable, which is then set to the `detailCalloutAccessoryView` a little farther down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I think I figured it out:

I removed the if/else checking mapView.selectedAnnotations.

```
let cpa = annotation as! CustomPointAnnotation

    anView!.image = UIImage(named:cpa.imageName)

    let rightButton: UIButton = UIButton(type: .DetailDisclosure)
    rightButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "arrow-icon.png"), forState: .Normal)
    rightButton.tintColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    rightButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("showItemDetail:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    anView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton

    fullImageOfItem = cpa.theImage

    let myCustomImage: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: fullImageOfItem)

    //anView!.leftCalloutAccessoryView = myCustomImage

    anView!.detailCalloutAccessoryView = myCustomImage

    return anView
```

I simply set my `fullImageOfitem` variable to `cpa.theImage` which is an instance of my custom annotation class. In the first line of the code, I set `cpa` to the annotation (passed into the function automatically) cast as my `CustomPointAnnotation`. And it seems to be working!